# How to repair gore-tex boots split?

Tags: gear, boots, gear-care, gore-tex, repairs

Last year I got myself a first pair of gore-tex B0 boots. Before I used only leather. I took care of those as good as I could. Keeping clean and using special sprays.

However now one boot developed 1.5 cm split in gote-tex surface. I tried to fix it with Sugru, a self-setting rubber that is advertised as able to fix mountaineering boots top. After an 8 hour hike on mixed terrain of trail, snow and rock it failed by breaking in multiple places and opening the split.

I would sew with glue a leather boot, but what should I do about gore-tex one?

Comment: So far I tried Sugru. Self-setting rubber that is advertised as able to fix mountaineering boots top. After 8 hour hike on mixed terrain of trail, snow and rock it failed by breaking in multiple places and opening the split.

Comment: Could you post a photo of the split?

Comment: Has it actually punctured the goretex or just the outer? The goretex layer is typically not the outermost layer, it will be either inside the boot or between the outer and inner.

Comment: Where are two layers attached one to another. The outer seems like nylon shell that the gore-tex is. The inner is soft and my guess was it's some kind of foam. I am away from home for the weekend and will be able to take a photo of the split only on Monday.

Comment: Your boot will likely be made of 3 layers, a breathable durable outer layer (this is neither waterproof nor the goretex) then a goretex liner (sometimes bonded directly to the outer), then an innner liner (to protect the goretex). If you've not punctured all the way though the boot it may well still be waterproof, i.e. if the goretex layer is still intact.

Comment: If you've punctured though the gortex. Your screwed. It will always leak, buy some new boots! Sorry!

Comment: use Shoe Goo - pretty neat stuff and much more durable than Sugru.

Answer (score 4):

You can find some goretex patches that you can use to repair.
I fixed a pair of gaiters where crampons opened a whole on the side using one of those patches. I didn't turn up very good but I think it was my job instead of the patch itself. :)

Goretex website has some information. I haven't used goretex for a while so I don't know how things are.

[Repair Information (Gortex)](http://www.gore-tex.com/remote/Satellite/content/care-center/repair-information)

Comment: Are they meant for boots? All the appliances of those I can find are on gloves, trousers, jacket, but not boots.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't understand your problem fully. As far as I know, in boots, the goretex liner is in between the outer fabric (nobuck, polyester mesh) and the inner. So I don't know how you split just the goretex liner. That said, with one of those patches, and some careful hand work, you should be able to sew back and seal properly. I'm more like a practical guy so I don't know how to help without seeing the thing.